# Is it appropriate (as a Catholic) to make the sign of the cross when passing an Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox or Church of the East church?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, religious-practice, oriental-orthodox, sign-of-the-cross

It is an old tradition in Catholicism to make the sign of the cross when passing a Catholic church, as a sign of respect to the Eucharist contained in the tabernacle, located within the Church.

I am wondering:

1. Do Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, and Church of the East also have tabernacles in their churches?
2. If they do, is it appropriate for a Catholic to make the sign of the cross when passing these churches?

Comment: In France, men also remove their hats!

Answer (score 7):

**Is it appropriate for a Catholic to make the sign of the cross when passing an Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox or Church of the East church?**

**Of course it is!**

It is also a tradition for some Catholics to make the sign of the cross when passing in front of cemeteries, whether a Catholic one or otherwise. Of course there would be some of the faithful departed in many of these cemeteries I imagine.

Seeing that the Orthodox Church does have valid sacraments which includes the  Eucharist, it would be appropriate for a Catholic to make the sign of the cross when passing in front of a Orthodox church in order to show an external sign of **respect of the real presence of Jesus Christ** in the consecrated host.

Yes, the Orthodox Churches do have tabernacles in their churches (No. 8) as this image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Orthodox_church_architecture) shows:

[image: Orthodox church building]

Answer (score 4):

Of course Eastern Orthodox church, like Russian, or Greek, have the tabernacles of Eucharist gifts in their churches. Orthodox christians called it as `kibot` (ru: `Кивот`, gr: `κῑβωτός`). It is always resided at the altar. Frequently, in modern time it has a form of mini church. Usually tabernacles is being covered with a glass hood, and the only bishops, priests, and deacons can touch the tabernacles.

The origin the of tabernacles is very ancient. In 4-th century many church writes note about a [`pidgins`](http://www.biblioteka3.ru/biblioteka/pravoslavnaja-bogoslovskaja-jenciklopedija/tom-4/darohranitelnica.html), which the Eucharist gist is kept in. Since the oriental churches, and churches of East, dissociated much later (in 5-6 cen.) it is allowed to think that they are also kept the ancient tradition to use the tabernacles.

Answer (score 3):

Although the Orthodox are, in the traditional Catholic view, schismatic, they do have valid priestly orders, which means they are able to validly consecrate the Eucharist, so I don't see what would be wrong with making the sign of the cross out of respect for the Real Presence of Jesus Christ in the Eucharist in these churches.

Comment: Happy to accept but I'm still wondering, do these churches store their eucharist in a tabernacle within the church? I peeked in a Greek Orthodox church yesterday and didn't notice anything resembling a tabernacle. Perhaps it was behind the iconostasis? Perhaps they consume all of the hosts at their service and there are no leftovers to store, in which it seems ambiguous whether i should make the sign of the cross

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle A show of respect is never out of order.  You could even, in the spirit of Christ, utter a small prayer of hope that we (Catholics) may be reconciled with our estranged Greek Orthodox brethren sooner rather than later.  That's the kind of thing that Jesus might do.

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle You are right in your guess, the Eucharist is stored in the altar, behind the iconostasis.

Comment: That is not scientific correct language, in sight of view of cathilicism, orthodoxy are schism, but in orthodox sight of view catholicism is a heresy, which is much worser.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ What heresy do they claim Catholicism holds?

Comment: @Geremia: I'm sure it's the _Filioque_, although the _real_ reason for the Great Schism was the issue with Petrine supremacy.

Comment: @Geremia - there are many  Catholic teachings that are claimed to be wrong by the Orthodox Church. The most important would be: Filioque; the purgatory; papal supremacy and infallibility; the Immaculate Conception; indulgences; clerical celibacy